# Why isn't my event added using addEventListener working?

Tags: actionscript, event-handling

I'm trying the [RestClientLib](https://github.com/logicminds/restclientlib) and my added eventlistener isn't fired.
I can't see why. Anyone has any ideas?

```
var restClient = new RestClient();

protected function btnInfo2_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    restClient.host = "somehost";
    restClient.port = "443";
    restClient.secure = true;

    restClient.setupRequest(RestClient.METHOD_GET, "somemethod");
    restClient.addparam("format","json");

    restClient.addEventListener(RestEvent.RESULT, onResult);
    restClient.sendrequest();               
}

protected function onResult(event:RestEvent):void
{
    trace("onResult");
}
```

If I put a breakpoint inside the source for the RestClient:

```
private function onResult(event:ResultEvent,token:Object=null):void
{
  trace("Reached onResult handler");
  var rawData:String = String(event.result);
  event.token.dispatchEvent(new RestEvent(RestEvent.RESULT, RestClient.SUCCESS, rawData,event.statusCode,null,event.token, true));
}
```

the data is actually received, but the Event is not propagated.

I have also tried settings bubbles to true, but no avail.

Comment: Can you post a link to this RestClient library? What is "event.token" in the onResult method? That's what is receiving the event, not RestClient.

Comment: @normmcgarry link is already provided

Comment: Sorry totally didn't realize that was a hyperlink. See response below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the event is dispatched on the event.token. This token looks like it is returned by the sendrequest method. So you'd add the listener like this:

```
var token:AsyncToken = restClient.sendrequest();  
token.addEventListener(RestEvent.RESULT, onResult);
```

Hope that works.

Comment: Well thank you Sir! (The RestClientLib author's example was misleading... )